# JS Bootstrap table to display boolean values as YES and NO instead 1 and 0

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have bootstrap table which fetches data from mysql db where I am having Boolean values which I want to display as YES or NO instead of 1 or 0 in my bootstrap table. My JS bootstrap table code

```
var $table = $('#table');
$table.bootstrapTable({
    url: 'list-user.php',
    search: true,
    pagination: true,
    buttonsClass: 'primary',
    showFooter: true,
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    columns: [{
        field: 'num',
        title: '#',
        sortable: true,
    }, {
        field: 'first',
        title: 'Available',
        sortable: true,

    },],

});
```

I am a learner, tried various online solutions but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Why not change the PHP script so that it produces YES/NO?

Comment: Thank you for your respond, that option won't work since the application is used by other program which required to have those values to be in bool.

Comment: Look into the `responseHandler` option in the documentation: you can replace what you want in the response before it is rendered in the table.

Comment: you can workaround with `$val?1:0;`

Comment: you can do with JQuery if you are using it: $('tableSelector').find('td:last-child').each(function() {this.html()==='true'? this.html('Yes'): this.html('No')}) is just a sample, can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formatter function - for example

```
function formatYesNo(value,row,index){
  return value==0 ? 'No' : 'Yes';

}
```

Define your column formatter like this:

formatter: formatYesNo,

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimkennelly/3cgxdp8o/)